# Android gcm notification payload vs data payload?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

According to 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref
gcm message can have notification payload or/and data payload
What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading on the link you send it is explained under [Payload section](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#payload)

> Payload
>
> Optional. If you are including a payload in the message, you use the
>   data parameter to include your custom key/value pairs. The client app
>   handles the data payload for display or other processing purposes.
>
> The notification parameter with predefined options indicates that GCM
>   will display the message on the client app’s behalf if the client app
>   implements GCMListenerService on Android, or if the notification
>   message is sent to an iOS device. This applies for both HTTP and XMPP.
>
> The app server can send a message including both notifications and
>   data payloads. In such cases, GCM handles displaying the notification
>   payload and the client app handles the data payload.
>
> See the Server Reference for details on sending and receiving
>   messages.

Comment: I tried to send notification message to my app and did not see anything happening, probably because i didn't implement GCMListenerService

Comment: I tried to send notification message to my app and did not see anything happening, probably because i didn't implement GCMListenerService. What is advantage of notification vs data and what is "display the message on the client app’s behalf"?

Comment: To test it you must use the right certificates on the server and matching when you build the app. Have you setup that part?

Comment: If you get the message: "Failed to show notification: Missing icon". Then you need to add the icon key.

        "icon" : "@drawable/ic_myicon"
or
        
    "icon" : "ic_launcher"

Comment: When I am sending both data and notification payload, the app shows the notification but GCMListener's onMessageReceived is not called. Can someone explain this behavior ?

Comment: @VaibhavGupta This sound like a seperate question.

Comment: @VaibhavGupta onMessageReceived will not be called in that case, instead the data payload will be delivered in the intent of the activiity you choose to open. 
"When optional data is provided, it is sent to the client app once user clicks on the notification and opens the client app."
ref : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: i am facing some other observation. When i am sending a notification(no data) payload, then the android notification is shown only if my app is not in foreground. If the app is in foreground the onMessageReceived() is called with null data. 
I was about to post a separate question for this , but thought to ask here in case it was a silly mistake on my side,

Comment: update on my above comment. My query has been solved :
[Check it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018084/gcm-3-0-notification-payload-not-showing-android-notification-when-app-is-in-for)

Answer (score 2):

You may find this explanation more helpful

Use scenario

> Notification: GCM automatically displays the message to end user devices on behalf of the client app. Notifications have a pre-defined set of user-visible keys.
>
> Data:  Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key/value pairs.

How to send

> Notification: Set notification payload. May have optional data payload. Always collapsible.
>
> Data: Set data payload only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en