# FCM push notification and app process

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have some issues with push notifications from gcm/fcm. 
We are used to use APN on iOS and notifications are shown by the OS on the app behalf even without launching the app process in background.
On the FCM documentation it is stated that when using a **Notification message** we have this behavior:

> FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf
>   of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of
>   user-visible keys.

We have done some tests but it seems that on Android there isn't a system service that shows notifications on behalf of the app but there are just implementations of libraries that requires to run inside the app process. This cause issues on some devices (Asus, Huawei etc) when there are settings like Protected Apps and Auto-Start Manager that prevent the app process to start and run the FCM code.

So there is no system process on android that shows the notification without starting the app process?

Comment: If a user uses such an app to disable certain functionality, why would you want to get in their way?

Comment: @Luca Looz You are wrong only data payloads are handled by the app processes. You can use notification payloads that will be handled by the google play service. You may want to look here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/30586969/2618491

Comment: @TimCastelijns protected apps/auto-start manager by default blocks all apps except the most popular apps like Facebook or WhatsApp. However most users doesn't know that they will not receive notification from other apps due to this blocking mechanism

Comment: @LucaLooz oh sorry, that sucks. I have similar problems with samsung's smart manager.

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal we already know what the documentation states but after some tests it seems that while the FCM library format and shows notification without data payload it still requires to start the app process and this is blocked by AutoStart Manager or Protected Apps... So at the end the notification will not be displayed

Comment: @LucaLooz I don't thimk the notifications are not displayed due to the stopping of app process. Maybe the AutoStart Manager or other such systems are killing google play services or preventing it to start. I found the same problem with Huawei devices some times ago. Any way it sucks...